# Why is selenium giving NoSuchElementException when element definitely exists

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having a problem is selenium giving me NoSuchElementException when the element exists without a doubt.

Below is one example where it doesn't find an element and times out. I know the element with the given ID exists because I can see it in the source while the program is running but for some reason selenium can't find it. It doesn't throw an error in this case but it is the same problem as elsewhere in the code that does throw errors.

I have tried using xpath instead of id as well as using implicit waits before trying to find but it still doesn't work.

```
def waitforload(id):
    checktime = 0
    while True:
        try:
            x = webdriver.find_element_by_id(id)
            return True
        except:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            checktime += 0.5
            print(checktime)
            if checktime > TIMEOUT:
                return False
```

Comment: Any `iframe`s on the page?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: Run `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")` in the console of whatever browser you are in. If it returns any elements, you've got iframes, so then you'll need to see which one your element is in.

Comment: Ah, thank you. The list was empty though so no iframes.

Comment: @Selenques what about `webdriver.find_elements_by_tag_name("frame")`?

Answer (score 0):

Known issues:

1.iframe
2.Even if element have ID, which is must be UNIQUE, some engines can generate two or more elements with same ID. Check that!
3.Maybe element is have hidden clone if it is input etc. Also, check that!